# Mutli feature polyline into individual features polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

Is there a tool which can split mutli feature polyline into an individual feature polyline, without spliting polylines that cross other polylines in the same shapefile?

Comment: Try the "multipart to single part" tool: resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003r000000

Comment: It splits at all the locations where polylines crosses. which should not be taken place for me.

Comment: ah, you want to convert a multipart feature to a single single part feature...

Comment: Yes, but at the same time it should not split the line where it crisscrosses with other lines in the same shapefile

Comment: Then after using Multipart to Singlepart, you should run Dissolve with all fields checked (except OBJECTID and shape fields of course).

Comment: Can you provide some graphic examples of what you're trying to do? A line is either multipart or it isn't. Making it single part won't affect other lines or split them where they cross. If you have branching polylines, those will be split at intersections because they are multipart (a line can have only two endpoints, else it is multipart). Are you trying to separate the disconnected parts of a multipart while preserving the connected parts as multipart? Another option to pay attention to in the Dissolve tool GISGe mentions is the 'unsplit lines' parameter.